# Why it is able to import a module that does not exist?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

A core.py file doesn't exist in the file folder named QtRec. But the author uses

```
QtRec.core._QApp_running = True
```

How can that work.
The example file is on [github](https://github.com/radjkarl/QtRec), created by radjkarl.

Another question is that I can't install the setup.py file. 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
How can I do.

Answer (score 3):

`core` is defined in the `__init__.py` file: see [the code](https://github.com/radjkarl/QtRec/blob/master/QtRec/__init__.py#L51).

Comment: Oh,I see.Can you install  setup.py successfully?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. How are you installing it?

Comment: Typing 'python setup.py install' in  command prompt (cmd) in Windows environment .Error message: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.